# Determing the highest possible color and depth attachement sampled count in Vulkan

Tags: graphics, vulkan

Do I need to set the value of `VkAttachmentDescription::samples` to a power of 2 or are arbitrary values allowed, as long as they don't exceed the maximum supported by the hardware?

I'm really confused about this. The `samples` field is of type `VkSampleCountFlagBits`, which is declared in the following way

```
typedef enum VkSampleCountFlagBits {
    VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT = 0x00000001,
    VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_2_BIT = 0x00000002,
    VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_4_BIT = 0x00000004,
    VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_8_BIT = 0x00000008,
    VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_16_BIT = 0x00000010,
    VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_32_BIT = 0x00000020,
    VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_64_BIT = 0x00000040,
    VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_FLAG_BITS_MAX_ENUM = 0x7FFFFFFF
} VkSampleCountFlagBits;
```

On the other hand, the `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits` struct contains the fields `framebufferColorSampleCounts` and `framebufferDepthSampleCounts`, which are of type `VkSampleCountFlags`, which in turn is simply a `typedef` for `uint32_t`.

The [vulkan-tutorial page on multisampling](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Multisampling#page_Getting-available-sample-count) determines the highest bit in these fields to compute the maximal usable sampled count. I actually don't get this. What if, for example, `VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_16_BIT` and `VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT` are both set in these fields? Doesn't that mean that the maximal usable sampled count is at least 17?

What I need to do at the end of the day is, given a `uint32_t requested_sampled_count`, determine whether `requested_sampled_count` is a possible value for `VkAttachmentDescription::samples` for *both* color and depth attachements and, if it's not, what is the highest possible value smaller than `requested_sampled_count`.

### **EDIT**:

Say I have given a `std::uint32_t sample_count` and, from the physical device properties, `VkSampleCountFlags framebuffer_color_sample_counts` and want to compute the `VkSampleCountFlagBits samples`. Do I need to this in the following way?

```
if (sample_count > 64)
    /* error */;
if (sample_count > 32)
    samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_32_BIT;
else if (sample_count > 16)
    samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_16_BIT;
else if (sample_count > 8)
    samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_8_BIT;
else if (sample_count > 4)
    samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_4_BIT;
else if (sample_count > 2)
    samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_2_BIT;
else if (sample_count == 1)
    samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
else
    /* error */;
```

Comment: That's what I expected you would have to implement yes.  I imagine you will be doing a lot of mapping of integer masks to/from enumerations across your code-base so you might want to consider crafting some helper methods.  I have a Java-based Vulkan implementation that does just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample counts in the `VkSampleCountFlagsBits` enumeration are a bit-mask of the *available* settings for the number of sampled bits in an attachment, so in your example the hardware supports **either** one **or** 16 samples (not 17!)

Comment: So, in general, only powers of $2$ are supported, right?

Comment: Yes, although I would still use the enumeration bit masks rather than any power-of-two maths, just to make the purpose of the code clearer.

Comment: I'm asking cause I need to adopt to an interface which gives me a `uint32_t` for the sample count. I guess the best solution is to `&` this sample count against the enumeration bit masks and use the largest nonzero one.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes that's exactly the approach I expect you have to take - basically a for loop over the bit mask testing each to enumerate the values from `VkSampleCountFlagBits` and then you can apply your logic to work out the highest for the colour and depth attachments.

Comment: Please take note of my edit. Is this how I need to do it?